# Testing loading and error state with kotlin coroutine

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, kotlinx.coroutines

Is there a way for me to mock a suspend function so that it never emit data or it will emit error. With RxJava 2, I can mock the function to return either Observable.error or Observable.never but I couldn't find an equivalent feature in kotlin coroutine. Here's the function that need to be mocked.

```
override suspend fun execute(param: Params): List<NewsModel> {
    return dataManager.getNewsCoro(param.newsType)
}
```

From my viewModel I'm calling the suspend function in this way

```
 fun getNews(newsType: NewsType) {

    liveData.postValue(NewsViewState(AsyncViewResource.loading()))

    launch {
      tryCatchFinally({
        val newsList = getNews.execute(GetNewsCoro.Params(newsType))
        liveData.postValue(NewsViewState(AsyncViewResource.success(newsList)))
      }, {

        liveData.postValue(NewsViewState(AsyncViewResource.error(it)))
      }, {}, false)
    }

  }
```

In the test class for that viewModel, I want to mock the the execute function so that it never return data, so that I can test whether the data passed into the liveData is the one I'm expecting. In RxJava, I can just mock the function to return Observable.never() and Observable.error(). However with coroutine, I'm lost on finding a way to mock it.

Comment: I don't know how mocking interoperates with suspendable functions, but making it return nothing is trivial: `suspend fun execute(...): List<NewsModel> { suspendCoroutine<Unit> {}; return whatever // you'll never reach this }`

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik if you do that, the test never ends because the thread is blocked?

Comment: Only if you set it up to wait until the coroutine completes, for example by using `runBlocking`. You can use `launch(Unconfined)`, which will immediately run your coroutine until the first suspension point. Then you don't need to wrap that in `runBlocking` and no threads will be blocking.

Comment: But to mock the function with mocktio, you have to use runBlocking. Otherwise due to thread difference. you can't be sure if it's really mocked.

Comment: Sounds like you want your cake and eat it, too. If you suspend the coroutine forever, then `runBlocking` will block forever. You can cancel the Job you got from `launch` in cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pauseDispatcher()` to pause your `TestCoroutineDispatcher`.

As per [doc](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-test/kotlinx.coroutines.test/-delay-controller/pause-dispatcher.html):

> When paused, the dispatcher will not execute any coroutines automatically, and you must call runCurrent or advanceTimeBy, or advanceUntilIdle to execute coroutines.

```
@Test
fun test() {
  val testCoroutineDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()
  val testCoroutineScope = TestCoroutineScope(testCoroutineDispatcher)
  testCoroutineScope.run {
    testCoroutineDispatcher.pauseDispatcher()

    viewModel.getNews(newsType)

     // Check if liveData is loading state or not.
  }
}
```